# Star rating in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Is there a way to add a rating button to a matlab GUI?

something like that
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

Comment: Thanks, but it's a different question

Comment: Assuming you want all the functionality described it is indeed not a duplicate. I have edited your post to provide some detail, please check whether it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own rating system
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41997-star-rating

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't a built in UIControl that provides this functionality. The closest control that I can think of is [slider](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoip6). Specify the MIN, MAX, and step size and the user will be bound to forced to select one of a few specific values.

Other options integrating a JAVA component into your GUI

- http://blog.noblemaster.com/2010/08/31/star-rating-panel-for-java-swing/
- http://code.google.com/p/starrating/

Or you can come up with a clever way to do it in matlab using a collection of radiobuttons and images.